# Search Multiple Tables and Produce Single Pageable Mixed ResultSet

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 4 Tables in SQL Server 2008 Database with Following Schema

```
Tutorials (TutorialID, Title, Approved, AddedDate)
Albums    (AlbumID, Title, Approved, AddedDate)
Profiles  (ProfileID, Title, Approved, AddedDate)
Polls     (PollID, Title, Approved, AddedDate)
```

I want to provide search facility that will search all these tables and will generate a single pageable result set showing mixed data of all tables.

Comment: i have a website that contains tutorials, albums, profiles and polls and i want to provide search facility that check the title column in all these columns using LIKE operator and display search results with paging.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a union view:

```
CREATE VIEW MixedData(Type, ID, Title, Approved, AddedDate) AS
    SELECT 'Tutorial' AS Type, TutorialID AS ID, Title, Approved, AddedDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Album'    AS Type, AlbumID    AS ID, Title, Approved, AddedDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Profile'  AS Type, ProfileID  AS ID, Title, Approved, AddedDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Poll'     AS Type, PollID     AS ID, Title, Approved, AddedDate
```

Then you can select from `MixedData` applying the criteria you want.  The 'AS Type' and 'AS ID' clauses aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: The problem with above solution is that if i am showing search results using the above View it will display all tutorials first then albums then profiles and in the end polls and if i am doing paging then first 100+ pages will show just tutorials until they finish and albums start.

Comment: So you need to do something cleverer, but you have to specify what order you want precisely.